# Add list values after comparison and condition check - Scala

Tags: scala

I have three lists inside a list.

```
val l = List(List(1, 0, 0), List(1, 1, 0), List(1, 0, 1))
```

Now the problem is to add the values inside list with condition check, basically I need to check each element wise values and if they are equal do some calculation if not do another calculation. I tired to group same element positions using transpose, then map the result and make comparison of current element with previous element in the list, I think the last part is where I am not clear.

EDIT:

Some more explanation, let say we have list like this

```
    List(List(i1, j1, k1), List(i2, j2, k2), List(in, jn, kn))
```

if i1 is equal to i2 then  1+i1+ i2*0.5 and j1 equal to j2 then 1+j1+j2*.0.5 and it goes upto kn
and the second condition is if they are not equal
i1 is not equal to i2 then it is a decrease, it will be i1+i2*0.5

hope this is explanation helps

Output I looking for

```
List[Double] = List(2.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make sense (which is why you are asking the question in the first place) ... so, it is not very useful to to paste it here in place of explanation of what you are trying to do ... 
You have to explain it in human words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is still very confusing but I think maybe something like this is what you're after.

```
val lst = List(List(1, 0, 0), List(1, 1, 0), List(1, 0, 1))

lst.transpose
   .map(sublst => sublst.sum*0.5 + (if (sublst.forall(_==sublst.head)) 1 else 0))
//res0: List[Double] = List(2.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

If all the elements of the sub-list are the same, add `1` to the calculation, else add `0`.

Comment: so if I understand, you are  checking the sub list elements with the first element then give 1 , when we transpose all the elements in the same coordinates are grouped as a list like - res11: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 1, 1), List(0, 1, 0), List(0, 0, 1)) then the comparison only inside each of the inner list , for instance for the first inner list  List(1, 1, 1) , they are all repeated and so it is a increase

Comment: That's right. If the sub-list has all the same values, like `List(1,1,1)` or `List(0,0,0)`, then the test `forall(_==sublst.head)` will return **true**. All elements of the `List` are compared to the head of the `List`.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, is there a way I can initialize the sum with 0.0 as the start of the addition, like a counter, when the first equal pair found or not found, the star sum value should be 0.0.

Comment: @Masterbuilder; The `.sum` of an empty `List[Int]` is `0` (an `Int`). The `.sum` of an empty `List[Double]` is `0.0`. If you don't want to change the `List` type to `Double` then just change the subsequent addition values (`1` and `0`) to `Double` (i.e. `1.0` and `0.0`) and you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst.transpose.map(v=>if(v.forall(_==v.head)) v.sum*0.5+1 else v.sum*0.5))
```

***or***

```
lst.transpose.map(v=>if(v.exists(_!=v.head)) v.sum*0.5 else v.sum*0.5+1)
```

***or***

```
lst.transpose.map(v=>if(v.find(_!=v.head)!=None) v.sum*0.5 else v.sum*0.5+1)
```

These are in general, can be used for `two different expressions` to be evaluated for the two different cases ie., `all elements equal or not equal` in the lists after calling `transpose` function.ie.,

```
lst.transpose.map(v=>if(v.exists(_!=v.head)) 
                     (Expression1 in terms of elements in v) 
                     else (Expression2 in terms of elements in v) )
```

**In Scala REPL:**
 for,
     `val lst = List(List(1, 0, 0), List(1, 1, 0), List(1, 0, 1))`

```
scala> lst.transpose.map(v=>if(v.forall(_==v.head)) v.sum*0.5+1 else v.sum*0.5)
res23: List[Double] = List(2.5, 0.5, 0.5)

scala> lst.transpose.map(v=>if(v.exists(_!=v.head)) v.sum*0.5 else v.sum*0.5+1)
res24: List[Double] = List(2.5, 0.5, 0.5)

scala> lst.transpose.map(v=>if(v.find(_!=v.head)!=None) v.sum*0.5 else v.sum*0.5+1)
res25: List[Double] = List(2.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and pattern matching

```
val list = List(List(1, 0, 0), List(1, 1, 0), List(1, 0, 1))

val result = list.transpose.map {
  case sublist if sublist.forall(sublist.head == _) => 1+0.5*sublist.sum
  case sublist => 0.5*sublist.sum
}
```